# Template for shared instances

Tags: c++, templates, coding-style, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to standardize and simplify a coding pattern I regularly re-use for shared object instances that does not rely on old, C-style macros for replicated code.

The example below represents the general coding pattern - e.g., `getInstance()`, `reset()`, declaring `sObjectInstance`, defining the `std::shared_ptr`, etc. – that I want to be able to re-use and standardize.  It also includes things that are specific to the example `ShaderOptions` class (e.g., sampling quality support), since I need a solution that supports class-specific members, enums, functions, etc.

I know that I could use C macros, for example `DECLARE_SHARED_POINTER( ShaderOptions )`, but I'm hoping to find a cleaner, more C++ way.

```
#pragma once

#include "cinder/CinderAssert.h"

#include <memory>

typedef std::shared_ptr<class ShaderOptions> ShaderOptionsPtr;

class ShaderOptions
{
public:

    // Sampling quality.
    enum SamplingQuality
    {
        NORMAL,
        HIGH
    };

    // Total sampling qualities.
    static const size_t TOTAL_SAMPLING_QUALITIES = (size_t)SamplingQuality::HIGH+1;

    //! Get the object instance.
    static ShaderOptionsPtr getInstance()
    {
        if ( !sObjectInstance ) {
            sObjectInstance = ShaderOptionsPtr( new ShaderOptions );
        }
        CI_ASSERT( sObjectInstance );
        return sObjectInstance;
    }

    //! Reset the object instance.
    static void reset() { sObjectInstance.reset(); }

    //! Set the sampling quality.
    void setSamplingQuality( const SamplingQuality samplingQuality )    { mSamplingQuality = samplingQuality; }
    SamplingQuality getSamplingQuality() const                          { return mSamplingQuality; }

private:

    //! Construct the shader options.
    ShaderOptions() {}

    //! Sampling quality.
    SamplingQuality                     mSamplingQuality            = SamplingQuality::NORMAL;

    //! Shared object instance.
    inline static ShaderOptionsPtr      sObjectInstance;
};
```

Note that my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954911/macro-alternative-for-c-code-generation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698073/c-alternatives-to-preprocessor-macro-code-generation), but I didn't feel like the issue has been fully answered.

Comment: Do you really need that pseudo-singleton?

Comment: Why not post your macro solution and ask how it can be improved. Very hard to understand where you are trying to get to at the moment.

Comment: And CRTP might help to factorize that.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42!  That's exactly what I need.  (Found a description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).)